# jQuery click event custom attribute undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've some buttons on my page. The mockup looks like this

```
<button type="button" class="js-category-delete" data-id="1">
    Delete
</button>
```

The goal is to get the value of the `data-id` attribute. Currently I'm using this javascript.

```
jQuery('.js-category-delete').on('click', (event) => {
    let id = jQuery(this).attr('data-id');   
});
```

My problem is that when I log the value to my browser console `console.log(id);` I the value of the `id` variable is `undefined`.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) implies the value of **this** is not the one you intend.
In this case you need to use **event.target**:

```js
jQuery('.js-category-delete').on('click', (event) => {
        let id = jQuery(event.target).attr('data-id');
        console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="js-category-delete" data-id="1">
    Delete
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

To suggest you an alternative way:

```js
$('.js-category-delete').on('click', function (event) {
  const clickedItem = jQuery(this); // and also jQuery(event.target)
  const id = clickedItem.data('id');
  console.log(id);
});
```

The `function` keyword makes `this` what you've expected at first.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Pen: https://codepen.io/shifu462/pen/WVaGLB

---

Also, as a shortcut for

```
jQuery(event.target).attr('data-id');
```

I've used here another jQuery method to get the value of a data attribute.

```
jQuery(event.target).data('id');
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/data/